# AVCam и фильтры

Tags: ios, xcode, видео, avfoundation

Может знает кто-нибудь способ подключить фильтры к [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/AVCam_AAPLAppDelegate_m.html). В гугле толком найти не смог. Конкретно интересует наложение фильтров к видео.

Comment: вопрос закрыт!!